# Single Sign On Issue

Tags: windows-7

I am using a Network Inventory tool and am having issues with single sign on.

In this company we each have two accounts; one day-to-day login account and one admin account that has domain admin privileges.

When enabling single sign on, when I open the tool in the browser, it uses my admin account - not my day-to-day account that I am signed into my computer with.

I have tried removing my profile from this PC and the issue persists. It is also a problem on other computers. It is functioning as expected for other members of the team. I'm not entirely sure how to troubleshoot. Does anybody have any pointers?

Comment: Get with your company's IT department. They're best equipped to help you resolve an issue like this.

Comment: Sadly I am the IT department.. Can you point to any resources?